# Mudar NAV e DOT Owl Carousel 2

Tags: jquery, carousel, owl-carousel

Estou usando o Owl Carousel 2, porém não estou conseguindo fazer essas alterações da imagem abaixo. Preciso mudar a posição da NAVs e DOTs para dentro do banner, se puderem da uma força eu agradeço.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2):

Pra quem estiver com essa dúvida consegui criando uma classe own-carousel-top, depois fazendo a chamada dela na DIV, segue os dados:

```
.owl-carousel-top .owl-next, .owl-carousel-top .owl-prev {
    top: 28%!important;
    opacity: .5;
    position: absolute;
    background: none!important;
    font-size:100px!important;
}

.owl-carousel-top .owl-next {
    right:2%;
    0px!important;*/
}

.owl-carousel-top .owl-prev {
    left:2%;
    0px!important;*/
}

.owl-carousel-top .owl-next:hover, .owl-carousel-top .owl-prev:hover{

    opacity: .9;

}
```

A variação vai de acordo com seu layout, podendo criar media querys para as diferentes resoluções.